# Hooks useCallback keeps using old values when refreshing list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

What is wrong with the useCallback below that I do not get the values below every time the function `onRefresh` is called ?
How can I make it return the expected values `using Hooks`?

**Example when I call onRefresh 2x**

values expected:

```
true
0
20
false

true
0
20
false
```

values: received

```
false
0
0
false

false
20
20
false
```

initialization of the state variables

```
const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false)
const [offsetQuestions, setOffsetQuestions] = useState(0)
```

Function call with useCallback:

```
const fetchSomeData = async () => {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000)) // 3 sec
}

const onRefresh = useCallback( async () => {
  setRefreshing(true)
  setOffsetQuestions(0)
  console.log(refreshing)
  console.log(offsetQuestions)

  await fetchSomeData()

  setOffsetQuestions(20)
  setRefreshing(false)
  console.log(offsetQuestions)
  console.log(refreshing)
}, [refreshing, offsetQuestions])
```

Where the function is called:

```
<FlatList
   data={questionsLocal}
   refreshing={refreshing}
   onRefresh={onRefresh}
   ...
/>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**What you are getting is the expected behaviour in hooks.** It's all about **closures**. Each render in react has its own props, state, functions and event handlers and they forever stay the same for that particular render. So whats happening here is that the `useCallback` is **closing** over the state variables for that particular render, So the `console.log` even after a `setState` will always give you the value of the state for that particular render because of **closure**.

Comment: Could you also reply to second part of the question: "How can I make it return the expected values using Hooks?"?

Comment: @justdvl Like I said above, what you are getting from the console logs is the **expected** behaviour in react hooks, its all about closures. Rather explain why you would want to immediately get/read the updated values within the same function just after calls to ```setRefreshing``` and I can help solve that.

Answer (score 6):

This situation confuses many developers who start using hooks. You would expect that React will be reactive and will change the value of the state after you called the `setX`, but if you think about it, you can not expect React to stop the execution flow change the state variable and continue execution.

So, what you are getting is the state variable from the scope of the creation of the `useCallback` (Read it again and again).

Let's break it down to two parts, the scope, and useCallback, as these are two different things you must understand to be able to use `useState` and `useCallback`.

**Scope:**

Lets say that you have a state called `age` and a function that write/reads this state (For now, without using `useCallback`)

```
const [age, setAge] = useState(42);

const increaseAge = () => {
  setAge(age + 1);   // this "age" is the same "age" from above 
  console.log(age);  // also this one
}
```

From this you can see that every render a new `age` variable is defined (The value if given by React), also a new `increaseAge` function is defined with access to the scope that holds the `age` variable.

This is how the scope works, this is why you don't get a new value of `age` just after calling `setAge`. To be able to get a new value on `age` React will have to re-render the component, so a new `age` variable will be defined on a new scope. And this is exactly what happens after calling `setAge`, React will trigger a new render.

**useCallback**

Now, let's say that you don't want to define the `increaseAge` function again and again, you want to keep the same reference (Can help preventing useless renders). This is where you'd want to use `useCallback`.

When using `useCallback`, React provides the same function reference each render, **unless** one of the dependencies changes.

Without giving the `useCallback` the dependencies, React will not recreate the function and the function will access to the scope that it was created on (First render), when giving the `useCallback` the correct dependencies, it will be recreated, and now have access to the scope with the latest state variable.

This should explain why you must provide dependencies, and how state variables are accessed (scope).

Answer (score 0):

You can use UseRef hook to use the current value of state instead of lexical value.

```
const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
```

This how you can set value in a reference and use it wherever you want.

Below is the link where you can understand this problem in detail and with possible solutions
https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/

Thanks